# Dropdown menu not overlapping lower elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I understand that this is a duplicate question. However, 
I have been messing around with the CSS for hours and cannot seem to get this right. My drop-down menus will not overlap and I believe that I have messed around so much that I have genuinely confused myself. Any help would be much appreciated!

** Note, the drop-down menu's are 'displacing' the other content & not underlaying as suggested by the comment mentioning "Z-index".

Possibly due to using display:Block & inline-block.

Here is a snippet...

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
 <body>
    <h3>Select times you will be in your office:</h3>

  <p class="daysOfTheWeek"><b><u>Monday</u></b></p>
  <div class="diffTimes">
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListMon1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)   
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;'
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListMon2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;'
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListMon3" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)  
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListMon4" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)   
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListMon5" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)    
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListMon6" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;'   
                                onblur="this.size=0;"></select>
  </div>

<p class="daysOfTheWeek"><b><u>Tuesday</u></b></p>
<div class="diffTimes">
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListTue1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)     
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListTue2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListTue3" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)   
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListTue4" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListTue5" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)   
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListTue6" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
</div>

<p class="daysOfTheWeek"><b><u>Wednesday</u></b></p>
<div class="diffTimes">
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListWed1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)    
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListWed2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)   
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListWed3" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListWed4" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)    
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;"></select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListWed5" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)    
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListWed6" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
</div>

<p class="daysOfTheWeek"><b><u>Thursday</u></b></p>
<div class="diffTimes">
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListThur1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                 {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                 onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListThur2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                 {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                 onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListThur3" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                 {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                 onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListThur4" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                 {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                 onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListThur5" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                 {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                 onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListThur6" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                 {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                 onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
</div>

<p class="daysOfTheWeek"><b><u>Friday</u></b></p>
<div class="diffTimes">
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListFri1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListFri2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListFri3" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListFri4" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListFri5" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListFri6" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
</div>

<p class="daysOfTheWeek"><b><u>Saturday</u></b></p>
<div class="diffTimes">
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListSat1" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListSat2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListSat3" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListSat4" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)  
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListSat5" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8)
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;"></select>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <select id="TimeListSat6" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8) 
                                {this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' 
                                onblur="this.size=0;">
      </select>
</div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
<h3 class="review">Review Changes</h3>
      <br>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Review Changes"   
       onclick="reviewFunc();"/>
<br>
<br>
<p><b><u>Monday</u></b></p>
<div class="reviewTimes">
    <p class="ey">From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText1" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText2" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText3" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText4" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText5" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText6" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
</div>

<p><b><u>Tuesday</u></b></p>
<div class="reviewTimes">
    <p class="ey">From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText21" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText22" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText23" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText24" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText25" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText26" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
</div>

<p><b><u>Wednesday</u></b></p>
<div class="reviewTimes">
    <p class="ey">From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText31" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText32" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText33" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText34" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;From:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText35" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
    <p class="ey">&nbsp;&nbsp;To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="myText36" class="ey" style="color:red"></p>
</div>

</body>

<script src="editSchedule.js"></script>

</html>
```

JavaScript

```
//Array of Office hours

TIMES = ["Select", "OUT", "8:00A", "8:30A", "9:00A", "9:30A", "10:00A", "10:30A", 
             "11:00A", "11:30A", "12:00P", "12:30P", "1:00P", "1:30P", "2:00P",  
             "2:30P", "3:00P", "3:30P", "4:00P", "4:30P", "5:00P", "5:30P", "6:00P"];

// TODO : create loop to create objects to simplify code
// function main() {
//     // Adding TIMES array to dropdown DOM
//
//     var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon1');
//
//     for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
//         var opt = document.createElement('option');
//         opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
//         opt.value = TIMES[i];
//         sel.appendChild(opt);
//     }
// }



//Function to pull selected values from dropdown menu for Days of week
function reviewFunc(){
    // Pull selected values for Monday
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 6) {
        var dropDownValue = document.getElementById("TimeListMon" + i);
        var selected = dropDownValue.options[dropDownValue.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("myText" + i).innerHTML = selected;
        i++;
    }
    // Pull selected values for Tuesday
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 6){
        var dropDownValue = document.getElementById("TimeListTue" + i);
        var selected = dropDownValue.options[dropDownValue.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("myText2" + i).innerHTML = selected;
        i++;

    }
    //Pull selected values for Wednesday
    i = 1;
    while (i <= 6){
        var dropDownValue = document.getElementById("TimeListWed" + i);
        var selected = dropDownValue.options[dropDownValue.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("myText3" + i).innerHTML = selected;
        i++;

    }
}










// Adding TIMES array to dropdown DOM

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon1');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon2');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon3');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon4');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon5');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListMon6');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListTue1');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListTue2');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListTue3');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}


var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListTue4');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListTue5');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListTue6');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}


var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListWed1');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListWed2');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListWed3');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListWed4');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListWed5');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListWed6');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}


var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListThur1');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListThur2');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListThur3');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListThur4');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListThur5');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListThur6');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListFri1');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListFri2');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListFri3');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListFri4');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListFri5');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListFri6');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}


var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListSat1');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListSat2');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListSat3');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListSat4');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListSat5');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}

var sel = document.getElementById('TimeListSat6');
for (var i = 0; i < TIMES.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = TIMES[i];
    opt.value = TIMES[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

CSS

```
.ey
{
    display:inline-block;
}

p.spaceRed
{
    display:inline-block;
    color: red;
}
form{
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.diffTimes {
    display:block;

}
div.reviewTimes {
    display: inline-block;
}
p.daysOfTheWeek {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

Comment: try using z-index

Comment: @AkhilAravind in `p.daysOfTheWeek`? and set it to what? `auto`?

Comment: its just a guide. i dont know much about css functionality. use google dev tools. inspect drop down menu, which is behind the block and then give z-index to that block.

Comment: You want to post a fiddle?

Comment: It's a lot of code without an inspector, but it sounds like your drop down is interacting with other elements on the page and you don't want it to. Sounds like you want display: absolute positioning?

Comment: @ElijahTate  https://jsfiddle.net/72dg15e9/1/    Although the functions are not working properly on fiddle. the dropdown shows the issues at hand

Comment: Yeah so the drop down is taking up the same space as the other elements on the page. So you want it to be absolute when it shows up. I will alter the fiddle and add an answer if I get some time.

Comment: @ElijahTateThanks for the help!

Comment: The inline JS is breaking the default behavior of absolute positioning on the select element. As a rule of thumb we don't usually want to inline our JS btw. https://jsfiddle.net/gysxfz3e/. Click on the first drop down and notice it working, then check the html to see I removed the JS. Notice the second is still broken. What were you trying to accomplish by altering the array?

Comment: @ElijahTate  Ahh i see. I was trying to make the dropdown show a list of 8 instead of the entire array dropdown spread across the screen. Is there a way to accomplish this while keeping the overlay?

Comment: This sums up the css needed to achieve what you want. As it turns out the drop down element is in accessible for styling so you have to be tricky with the CSS while using your JS approach. As suggested in the thread you should remove this to it's own file to finalize. MAIN THREAD :PAULOB ANSWERS https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/setting-length-of-dropdown-list-when-selected/300020/8I guess we have always built custom drop downs or used a library so was unfamiliar with this oddness of the select element.

Comment: Well either way, thank you for your time and effort. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! Just to clarify, a drop down consists of two elements. The button, and the drop down that contains the items. The button is clicked which shows the hidden drop down. The drop down needs to be absolutely positioned to not push around other elements. Normally to achieve what you wanted you would just alter the height of the DD, but since in is not accessible for styling here you have to make the entire select element absolute. This means that your parent relative element must have a fixed width. You will notice it is set at 200px. Which this is not ideal TBC

Comment: Say you have a DD that is bigger than 200px? Well now you need JS to set your parent width property dynamically. If they would have allowed the DD to be stylized, all this could be easily avoided. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I think you should make this an answer so I can accept it. This is a lot of very useful information. You're awesome!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)  Posted an answer!

Comment: What's with all the `&nbsp;&nbsp;`. Do you not know how to use margins? I recommend learning CSS completely. Get a book if you have to. Also, I noticed that you think `<option>`s have `.innerHTML` when they really have `.text`.

Comment: @PHPglue  You are very right. I have been sparse when it comes to using CSS at the beginning of this project as I am not so much focusing on the style as functionality. Obviously these both clashed and is causing me to rethink my approach. I am super noobie and will be looking into the .text. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drop down consists of two elements. The button, and the drop down that contains the items. The button is clicked which shows the hidden drop down. The drop down needs to be absolutely positioned to not push around other elements. Normally to achieve a shorter DD you would just alter the height of the DD, but since it is not accessible for styling, here you have to make the entire select element absolute. This means that your parent relative element must have a fixed width. You will notice it is set at 200px. Which this is not ideal. Say you have a DD that is bigger than 200px? Well now you need JS to set your parent width property dynamically. If they would have allowed the DD to be stylized, all this could be easily avoided.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/gysxfz3e/4/

1. Wrap your select in a parent element to apply relative positioning to:

   ```
   <div class="parentSelect">
       <select id="TimeListMon2" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;"></select>
   </div>
   ```
2. Create CSS for your parent and select elements:

   ```
   div.parentSelect{
     position: relative;
     width: 200px;
     display: inline-block;
     height: 15px;
   }

   div.parentSelect select{
     position: absolute;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

in your css you just need to do the `z-index: 99;` within the navigation bar component and that should fix your overlap problem

Comment: I do not have a navbar component. I have been tinkering with this forever. I wonder if I should post all of the code.

Comment: So in hindsight your drop down menu is not overlapping your material?

Comment: correct. it is pushing the other elements out of the way. I have the drop-downs set to display 5 values and then scroll.

Comment: Your ‘diffTimes’ is your dropdown can you specify what component or div where the drop down is made please

Comment: I am not sure of your question. I have all of the `divs` set to `class = diffTimes` and there are about 36 of them.

Comment: Okay I think you should post your whole code because it will help me see the problem

Comment: Done. I know there is a ton of redundancy but right now just focused on functionality and will compress later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that later you can migrate to mobile. It just shows some coding practices.

```js
var doc, get, post, M, I, special, unspecial, createDropdown; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){ // make sure DOM is loaded
doc = document;
get = function(url, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = function(){
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(send, url, success, context){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var c = context || this;
  x.open('POST', url); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.onload = function(){
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(typeof FormData !== 'undefined' && send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      var s, r = [];
      for(var p in send){
        s = send[p];
        if(typeof s === 'object')s = JSON.stringify(s);
        r.push(encodeURIComponent(p)+'='+encodeURIComponent(s));
      }
      x.send(r.join('&'));
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
special = function(str){ // for use with .innerHTML not .value or .text
  return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
unspecial = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
}
createDropdown = function(selectId, dropdownArray, appendToElement, selectOnchangeFunc){
  var sel = M('select'); sel.id = selectId;
  for(var i=0,opt,l=dropdownArray.length; i<l; i++){
    opt = M('option'); opt.text = opt.value = dropdownArray[i]; sel.add(opt);
  }
  sel.onchange = selectOnchangeFunc; appendToElement.appendChild(sel);
}
var times = ['OUT', '8:00A', '8:30A', '9:00A', '9:30A', '10:00A', '10:30A', '11:00A', '11:30A', '12:00P', '12:30P', '1:00P', '1:30P', '2:00P', '2:30P', '3:00P', '3:30P', '4:00P', '4:30P', '5:00P', '5:30P', '6:00P'];
var selectIds = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'], weekday_times = I('weekday_times'), dropdownData = {}, output = I('output');
function selectChange(){
  dropdownData[this.id] = this.value; output.innerHTML = special(JSON.stringify(dropdownData));
}
for(var i=0,si,l=selectIds.length; i<l; i++){
  si = selectIds[i]; dropdownData[si] = 'OUT';
  createDropdown(si, times, weekday_times, selectChange);
}
output.innerHTML = special(JSON.stringify(dropdownData));
I('content').style.display = 'block';
});// end load
//]]>
```

```css
*{
  padding:0; margin:0; box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%; background:#aaa; color:#000;
}
body{
  position:relative; font:22px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body>*{
  position:absolute;
}
#content{
  display:none; width:100%; height:100%; 
}
.page{
  position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; float:left;
}
.bar{
   width:100%; height:38px; padding:3px; background:#ccc; color:#000;
}
h1{
  font-size:28px; margin-left:3px;
}
.weekday{
  display:flex;
}
.weekday>*{
  flex:1; text-align:center; border:1px solid #000;
}
#overlap,#output{
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='page'>
      <div class='bar'><h1>Select times you will be in your office:</h1></div>
      <div class='main'>
        <div class='weekday'><label for='sun'>Sunday</label><label for='mon'>Monday</label><label for='tue'>Tuesday</label><label for='wed'>Wednesday</label><label for='thu'>Thursday</label><label for='fri'>Friday</label><label for='sat'>Saturday</label></div>
        <div class='weekday' id='weekday_times'></div>
        <div id='overlap'>dropdownData Looks Like:</div>
        <div id='output'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS for the data would be different if you were displaying it. You can loop over the `dropdownData` Object assigning it to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) as the link suggests, for use with XHR2.

Comment: Wow! This will be extremely helpful in the near future as I will have to make a mobile version of this. I appreciate you taking the time to explain and show examples to me!

Comment: Is this an example using JSON parsing?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(dropdownData)` creates the String. `FormData` objects can be sent to the Server. `JSON.parse(jsonStringHere)` is used on the Client on `json_encode($assocArray)`ed  data sent from the Server back to the Client. *(json_encode was PHP example - you may want Node with MongoDB)*

Comment: ahhh Ok. At some point I will have to pull the selected array items in the dd menus and write them out to CSV. Would you happen to know a good way to go about that? I haven't really started looking yet as I am still working on a few kinks.

Comment: [csv.js](https://csv.js.org/stringify/)  [example](https://csv.js.org/project/examples/)

Comment: Thank you! This will be a great head start!